# What Ion gets reduced in this aqueous electrolysis?

Tags: electrochemistry, electrons, electrolysis

In an electrolysis of tin(II) iodide ($\ce{SnI2}$) with led cathode and nickel anode, why is it that the tin ion gets reduced and not the nickel ion?

Comment: What nickel ion?

Comment: the nickel that gets oxidized

Comment: ok, but if the nickel gets oxidized, and then reduced, there is no net reaction, right?

Comment: yes, this is from a school assignment. I did a similar one where there was no net reaction also but I understood why. In this one I dont know why one takes precedence over the other

Comment: are you posting the full description of the problem?

Comment: The problem asks to write the ionization equations, the reduction and oxidation equations and the global equation